# ORACLE SQL case where with '>' operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table where each entry can have sequence number of 1 or 2. I want to choose one of these options based on the value of the current year. Is it possible to do the following in a where statement:

```
(CASE sequence_number 
    WHEN cy.curyr < '41' THEN '1' 
    ELSE '2' 
       END ) sequence_number
```

Comment: yes, you can put a `case` in a `where` statement, but do you need to do this? Don't you just want to put the `case` statement in your question into your `select` clause?

Comment: See the oracle docs - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm

Comment: Do not use string literals for numbers. `'41'` is a String, `41` is a number

Comment: Is that current year 41 A.D.? Is your database for time travellers? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct way in a where clause would be

```
and sequence_number = case when cy.curyr < '41' then 1 else 2 end
```

is `curyr` a string though?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
(CASE WHEN cy.curyr < '41' THEN '1' 
      ELSE '2' 
 END ) as sequence_number
```

In terms of your query, you simply need to remove the initial `sequence_number`.

Also, are you sure you want to do string comparisons?  When doing so, '5' < '41' evaluates to false.

If you don't want string comparisons:

```
(CASE WHEN cast(cy.curyr as int) < 41 THEN 1
      ELSE 2 
 END ) as sequence_number
```

Comment: select cy.curyr, ot.sequence_number
    from 
    organised_lbs ot, 
    curYrs cy,
       where
       ot.year = cy.curyr and
         (CASE WHEN cy.curyr < 41 THEN 1 
         ELSE 2 
         END ) as sequence_number
      group by cy.curyr;                                                            //this is the current query but I'm not sure where its going wrong